# Labels not updating

Tags: vba, excel, label, userform

I'm trying to update a label while a code executes. Now this works in two other userforms with exact the same code (to update) but in this one he doesn't want to update the info.

The strange thing is, when I execute the code line by line it will update it though. So the name of the labels etc are not wrong.

This is my code:

```
        Dim MSWorkbook As Workbook, MSSheet As Worksheet, GMSheet As Worksheet, i As Integer, LastRow As Integer, LastRowGM As Integer
        Dim aantal As Integer, ColNum As Integer

        'variabelen toewijzen
        Set GMSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Set MSWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("....")
        Set MSSheet = MSWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        GMSheet.Activate
        ColNum = 72 'letter H

        'progress bar opmaken
        ParetoPerCategorie.PGB.Max = 11
        ParetoPerCategorie.PGB.Min = 0
        ParetoPerCategorie.PGB.Value = 1
        ParetoPerCategorie.lblInfo.Caption = "Voorbereidend werk"

        LastRow = MSSheet.Range("G5").End(xlDown).Row
        LastRowGM = GMSheet.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row

        'Data ophalen (per categorie alle 40 getallen optellen en plaatsen in de juiste cel.
        For j = 3 To LastRowGM
            aantal = 0
            ParetoPerCategorie.lblInfo.Caption = "Bezig met categorie " & GMSheet.Range("A" & j).Value
            ParetoPerCategorie.lblAantal.Caption = "categorie " & j - 2 & " van de " & LastRowGM - 2
            ParetoPerCategorie.PGB.Value = j - 1
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

                For i = LastRow - 40 To LastRow
                    aantal = aantal + MSSheet.Cells(i, Chr(ColNum)).Value
                Next i
            GMSheet.Range("B" & j).Value = aantal
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
        Next j

        MSWorkbook.Close False
        Unload Me
```

I have no idea why it doesn't do it when I just run it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm just curious about this comment...`ColNum = 72 'letter H` ??

Comment: `MSWorkbook.Close False` - Is the userform in that workbook? if so change false to true.

Comment: @CallumDA 72 is the ASCII value of the letter H.

Comment: @Zerk No it isn't. But in fact since I use a userform it doesn't want to close the other workbook anymore.

Comment: I think I have found the answer to my own question.

If I only let update one label it works, so I do believe that it's maybe just because excel can't handle it that he doesn't do it as he should.

Comment: DoEvents  between updates to give excel a chance to redraw might work?

Comment: What do you mean @harassed dad

Comment: put the command 

 DoEvents

 after the line ParetoPerCategorie.lblAantal.Caption = "categorie ...